# From pulsar function how to send messages to different pulsar topic partition?

Tags: apache-pulsar

may I know from pulsar functions how to publish message(s)  to different pulsar topic partition based on hashing? . pulsar producer has various hashing schemes to send messages to different topic, like that i am looking for.

Comment: You want to have an option in Pulsar functions to define your own routing for output messages to partitions, right? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I am looking for.

Comment: I am not aware of any possible way to achieve it in Pulsar functions, but you can submit a feature request at https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues